# MS Access VBA trapping SQL Server Connection Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, odbc, dao, ms-access-2010

I'm Having problems getting Access (2010) VBA to trap errors for connections to a SQL Server (2008) for linking tables.

I'm getting an error and popup windows, presumably from the ODBC Driver? I want to suppress these and handle the error myself. I know about the DAO.errors and ADO.errors collections but these don't help if I can't get the error to call my error handler!

The code below will give the error (unless you happen to have a table called myTable in a database called myDatabase on a server called myServer).
I've tried to use ADODB rather than DAO but could not get this to work at all.
Any ideas?

```
Public Function main()
    Dim myDB As DAO.Database
    Dim myTabledef As DAO.TableDef

    On Error GoTo Err_handler

    Set myDB = CurrentDb
    Set myTabledef = myDB.CreateTableDef("l_table")

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    myTabledef.Connect = "odbc;driver=SqLServer;" & _
        "DATABASE=myDB;SERVER=myServer;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

    myTabledef.SourceTableName = "MyTable"

    myDB.TableDefs.Append myTabledef

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    Exit Function

Err_handler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Function
```

---

I made a mistake in the posted code {Sql Server} became SqLServer when I posted it.
So the full code that gives the error is below:

```
Public Function main()
Dim myDB As DAO.Database
Dim myTabledef As DAO.TableDef

On Error GoTo Err_handler

Set myDB = CurrentDb
Set myTabledef = myDB.CreateTableDef("l_table")

DoCmd.SetWarnings False

myTabledef.Connect = "odbc;driver={Sql Server};" & _
    "DATABASE=myDB;SERVER=myServer;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

myTabledef.SourceTableName = "MyTable"

myDB.TableDefs.Append myTabledef

DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Exit Function

Err_handler:
MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Function
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly a simple way would be to create a generic error handling sub that uses a select statement on the error number to handle the errors being raised, you could also log the errors [see here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-23b.html) essentially the `Err_handler:` label/block would call this routine passing any arguments etc it is however dependent on whether it is `on error goto` is being invoked

Answer (score 0):

The error will not occur until you try to append the TableDef

```
Dim myDB As DAO.Database
Dim myTabledef As DAO.TableDef

On Error GoTo Err_handler

Set myDB = CurrentDb
scn = "odbc;driver=SqLServer;" & _
"DATABASE=myDB;SERVER=myServer;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
Set myTabledef = myDB.CreateTableDef("l_table")

myTabledef.Connect = scn
myTabledef.SourceTableName = "Table1"
myDB.TableDefs.Append myTabledef

Err_handler:
Debug.Print Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
```

Comment: Yes that's right. But when the error does occur, I want to handle it in my error handling code rather than have a few pop-up windows from ODBC (or wherever). The erros can also occur if I lose the connection to the remote database after the program has started. The pop-up windows can then make it difficult for users to close the app as they keep popping back up again.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. The sample code goes to the error handler at the line that fails, at which point it can be handled in whatever way is appropriate.

Comment: @Fionnuala, I have "On Error goto", but the dialogue Kjay mentions seems to override that, and even "DoCmd.SetWarnings False"