# Why does this SQL statement ask for a value?

Tags: ms-access, append, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a form which lets you add names to the table and shows it in a dropdown menu. 
When I click on the form, it should ask the user to enter the name they would like to add and click "ok". Once the user clicks ok, the name should be stored in a table and added to the drop-down menu.

Every thing works fine but when the user types the value in the textbox and clicks "ok" a window pops up asking for the parameter value. Whatever the user types in this parameter value gets saved in the table instead of getting the value from the textbox. I am not sure why this happens.

Name is a string, is it the quatation marks?

Here is the code:

```
Dim test As String
test = Text1.Value
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO List_Of_Agencies(T_PI_GroupName)VALUES (" & test & ");"
Form_0_Cover.Combo2.Requery
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly read the [FAQ] -- you would not walk up to someone and ask "Append Query ACcess?" so please don't do that here. The question title should be an actual question. Also, please also take advantage of the wonderful tagging system and tag your questions appropriately so that others know what your question is about.

Comment: I did use the "Tagging System"

Comment: The `ms-access` tag is the most widely monitored and all questions about MS Access should ideally include this tag. This makes it much easier for SO users to search for Access related topics, rather than having to search for each sub tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO List_Of_Agencies(T_PI_GroupName) VALUES ('" & test & "')"
```

Comment: RunSQL runs with MS Access warnings. To run without the built-in warnings, use an instance of CurrentDB and Exceute the SQL string.

Comment: @Remou Can't you just use something like `DoCmd.SetWarnings = 0` beforehand?

Comment: @JP No, that is a bad idea. It masks errors you need to know about and is system wide, not confined to the Access application you are using, which means that you can cause havoc if you forget to Set Warnings off or even if someone switches from one application to another in between commands. You will find that most places in SO where set warnings have been mentioned, there is a comment suggesting that you  should not use it. This was also true on Tek-Tips, and, I suspect most Access forums.

Comment: @Remou Thank you, but I'm still confused. I'll post a question.

Comment: @JP here is an example, found very quickly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141130/ms-access-vba-trapping-sql-server-connection-error

Comment: @Remou It's like the OERN equivalent for Access. FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11213892/190829