# How to Catch SQL Error through Excel VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have a program that is going through the subfolders of a folder and running a stored SQL command on each. I am in the process of writing another module that will automatically check the files before being inputted, but I don't like having my company's test data hinging on a program without any way to know if something errored out. Here is the code I currently have:

```
Sub openConnection()

Set varConnection = New ADODB.Connection
Set varCommand = New ADODB.Command

varConnection.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=192.168.1.186,1433;INITIAL CATALOG=Test1; INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"
varConnection.Open

varCommand.CommandText = "importFile"
varCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
varCommand.ActiveConnection = varConnection

Set varParameter = varCommand.CreateParameter("filePath", adChar, adParamInput, Len(varFolderPath), varFolderPath)
varCommand.Parameters.Append varParameter

varCommand.Execute

varConnection.Close

End Sub
```

On occasion, the command will error out, causing the data to not be uploaded. How can I catch these ***SQL errors*** through Excel VBA in order to handle them appropriately without it being treated as though it had gone through like a normal file?

Note: I don't mind rewriting code- this is all still in alpha.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might be what you are looking for...

[**MS Access VBA trapping SQL Server Connection Error**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9141641/162167)

```
Sub OpenConnection()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    // Do your stuff here...

    ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    ' Or else you could log the error in a file, or even display a message box, whatever...'
End Sub
```

From the answer provided by [**fionnuala**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2548/fionnuala) to the above-linked question.

Comment: This did not work. I'm asking how to catch an SQL error, not a VBA error. I ran the same folder through the program in SQL Server Management Studio with a planted error and it gave me an error whereas the VBA program did not.

Comment: I read a post where it says that errors below number 19 are not reported back to VBA, hence perhaps the fact that the VBA can't trap it.